# Как правильно написать Response в Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

```
{"info":-[-{"success":true,
"object":-[-{"id":"743",
"pagetitle":"\u041a\u044d\u0448-\u042e",
"price":"7000-12000",
"titleCat":"\u0420\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b",
"map":"43.225252604744355,76.95571602834801",
"img":"assets\/uploads\/97\/2016-09-04_11-00-22_2.jpg",
"halal":"1",
"isAkc":"",
"address":"\u0433.\u0410\u043b\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044b, \u0425\u0430\u0434\u0436\u0438 \u041c\u0443\u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430 43, \u0443\u0433 \u041c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430.",
"work-day":"\u043f\u043d-\u0447\u0442 \u0441 10:00 \u0434\u043e 01:00 \u043f\u0442-\u0441\u0431 \u0441 11:00 \u0434\u043e 02:00",
"rating":"5"
},
```

_

```
 @GET("?act=object&cid=10&sort=1")
Call<ResturantResponse> getResturantList();

public class ResturantResponse {
@SerializedName("object")
private List<Resturant> object;

public List<Resturant> getObject() {
    return object;
}

public void setObject(List<Resturant> object) {
    this.object = object;
}
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_resturant);

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResturantResponse> call = apiInterface.getResturantList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResturantResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResturantResponse> call, Response<ResturantResponse> response) {
            List<Resturant> resturants = response.body().getObject();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new ResturantAdapter(resturants,R.layout.card_view_resturant,getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResturantResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("resturant",t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

я так написал Response но ответ пустой.

Comment: можно полностью json? по моему, структура не соответствует ответу. и минусы какие-то странные....

Comment: вот  json    {"info":[{"success":true,"object":[{"id":"743","pagetitle":"\u041a\u044d\u0448-\u042e","price":"7000-12000","titleCat":"\u0420\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0430\u043d\u044b","map":"43.225252604744355,76.95571602834801","img":"assets\/uploads\/97\/2016-09-04_11-00-22_2.jpg","halal":"1","isAkc":"","address":"\u0433.\u0410\u043b\u043c\u0430\u0442\u044b, \u0425\u0430\u0434\u0436\u0438 \u041c\u0443\u043a\u0430\u043d\u0430 43, \u0443\u0433 \u041c\u0435\u0434\u0438\u043a\u0443\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0430.","work-day":"\u043f\u043d-\u0447\u0442 \u0441 10:00 \u0434\u043e 01:00 \u043f\u0442

Answer (score 0):

Судя по json `YourResponse.java`:

```
public class YourResponse {
private final Info info;

public YourResponse(Info info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public class Info {
    private final boolean success;
    private final List<Resturant> object;

    public Info(boolean success, List<YourObject> object) {
        this.success = success;
        this.object = object;
    }
}

public class Resturant {
    private final String id;
    private final String pagetitle;
    private final String price;
    private final String titleCat;
    private final String map;
    private final String img;
    private final String halal;
    private final String isAks;
    private final String address;
    @SerializedName("work-day")
    private final String workDay;
    private final String rating;

    public Resturant(String id, String pagetitle, String price, String titleCat, String map, String img, String halal, String isAks, String address, String workDay, String rating) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pagetitle = pagetitle;
        this.price = price;
        this.titleCat = titleCat;
        this.map = map;
        this.img = img;
        this.halal = halal;
        this.isAks = isAks;
        this.address = address;
        this.workDay = workDay;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
}
```

Ну и `get`-еры для каждого поля